# IF statement returning false even when it's true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a script to order a spreadsheet rows by ascending date and it should hide all the rows where the month is not the same as we are currently in.
Here's the script:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Diário de Caixa');
  sheet.getRange('A3:M').activate();
  sheet.getActiveRange().sort({column: 6, ascending: true});
  var r = sheet.getRange('C3:C');
  var date = new Date();
  var mesAtual = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M");
  var v = r.getValues(); 
  for(var i=v.length+1;i>=0;i--){
    if(v[0,i]!=mesAtual){
    sheet.hideRows(i);
    }
  }
}
```

By the time I'm writing this question, I have data filled till the row 36, so the script should've been hiding all rows below the row 36, but it's hiding the rows 34, 35 and 36 too, even when their formula and value are equal as the rows 3 to 33 and all of them returns "1", that stands for January.

What's missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this `v[0,i]` should be `v[i][0]`

and this `var r = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow() -2);` would be better than this `var r = sheet.getRange('C3:C');` ... Take a look at this in the debugger. You often get nulls between getLastRow() and maxRows.

You could also use `var r = sheet.getRange('C3:C').getValues().filter(e => e[0]);` and eliminate the the nulls with falsy and truthy

You can also do a lot of date comparisons with valueOf() and getTime() since they both return milliseconds from a reference date and so you can compare them numerically.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper but the first [] stands for the columns and the second [] stands for the rows, isn't it? 

So v[0,i] keeps me in the first column from my range and the decreasing 'i' from the for loop checks if the actual month given in the "mesAtual" variable is different from the value in the range. If so, it should hide the row... the script is partially working as it hides all rows from 2000 to 33, the wrong thing is that it's hiding rows 36, 35 and 34 even when they have the exactly value and formula from rows 3 to 33

Comment: Just saw your edit, I'll try it. Thanks again!

Comment: The first [] is rows in this case and the second is columns and they must be written as V[i][0] because even a single column is a 2D array.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get why in this case the first [] is rows as V[0,i] was returning all values correctly and only the rows 34, 35 and 36 were incorrect. Anyway, I changed it to v[i][0] and now it's returning the "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Now I made an array of only one value, getting it from the row 34. It returned correctly the number 1, the problem is when the array have the length of the column C...

Comment: I think you running into the issue that when you specify ranges in that way google apps script returns nulls from getLastRow() to maxRows and so you either need to filter the nulls outs or use the getRange(row,col,numrows,numcols) method.

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for the responses yesterday. Just to be clear, I ended up reaching the results I wanted... I used this solution "var r = sheet.getRange('C3:C').getValues().filter(e => e[0]);" to keep the blank rows visible, but the way I was doing would work too. I kept the V[0,I] as it was working as intended... The only thing I needed to change to make it work was sheet.hideRows(i); to sheet.hideRows(i+3); because I'm using rows 1 and 2 as header.